# Change key in array based first element array multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to change key of array into first element array ?
I preferred using array_map.

Now I have a common array.
If I have an array like this :

```
[
 0 => [
    'barang_id' => '7389'
    'spec' => 'KCH8AT-DM'
    'heat_no' => '7B4784'
    'coil_no' => '0210'
    'size' => '17.9'
    'weight' => '2014'
    'container' => 'TCLU6265556'
]
 1 => [
    'barang_id' => '7390'
    'spec' => 'KCH8AT-DM'
    'heat_no' => '7B4784'
    'coil_no' => '0050'
    'size' => '17.9'
    'weight' => '2006'
    'container' => 'TCLU6265556'
 ]
]
```

I need like this. The value of first element array is going to be key of array.

```
[
 7389 => [
    'barang_id' => '7389'
    'spec' => 'KCH8AT-DM'
    'heat_no' => '7B4784'
    'coil_no' => '0210'
    'size' => '17.9'
    'weight' => '2014'
    'container' => 'TCLU6265556'
]
 7390 => [
    'barang_id' => '7390'
    'spec' => 'KCH8AT-DM'
    'heat_no' => '7B4784'
    'coil_no' => '0050'
    'size' => '17.9'
    'weight' => '2006'
    'container' => 'TCLU6265556'
 ]
]
```

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

I thought with this solution using array_map

```
$a = [['id' => 1233, 'name' => 'test1'], ['id' => 1313, 'name' => 'test2'], ['id' => 13123, 'name' => 'test3']];

$result = [];
array_map(
    function ($item, $key) use (&$result) {
        $result[$item['id']] = $item;
        return $item; // you can ignore this
    }, $a, array_keys($a)
);
```

now result contains what you want, check this image:

[image]

Or you could use it like this (without the $result thing) but you should unset the old key, look at the image: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you have only 2 values you can create a new array:

```
$newarray[7389] = $oldarray[0];
$newarray[7390] = $oldarray[1];
```

or if you have multiple values you can do:

```
$newarray =[];
foreach($oldarray as $value) {
$newarray[$value['barang_id']] = $value

}
```

demo:https://ideone.com/mm2T7T

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map), because `array_map` will not pass the keys to the callback. But [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) would work:

```
$reindexed = [];
array_walk($data, function($v, $k) use (&$reindexed) {
    $reindexed[$v['barang_id']] = $v;
});
```

This has no advantage over a plain old `foreach` though.

Comment: Would this be simpler with plain foreach?

Comment: @marekful yes, in my opinion a `foreach` would be simpler. it's more readable to me and it doesn't need a reference nor callback.